# MaTeX text looks shabby when latex generated pdf is not zoomed

Tags: plotting, matex

I want to use Matex for the figures in my plots which I eventually would like to use in overleaf. I create a plot and use Matex in it and right click on it to save as pdf. I then use this pdf in overleaf. So, when I compile the latex file and download the pdf, the Matex font looks rather shabby compared to other text on the plot (such as numbers on axes for which I didn't use mathematica) when I do not zoom in.

[image].

The font on latex can be seen on the description of the figure. The Matex font looks spotty with kinda white gaps in it. The problem with this is that when I print the file onto paper, the font doesn't look good.

I don't think the problem is resolution since when I zoom into the pdf file, I get a very sharp Matex font. Does anyone know what's going on?
[image]

Comment: what version of Matex? Which version of Mathematica? does this happen only when you use overleaf?

Comment: @Nasser Hi, I'm using the latest version of Matex. I'm having the same problem with versions 12.2 and 13.3 of mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser I don't think it has got to do with overleaf because when I save the plot as pdf, if i directly view the pdf of the plot, i get the same problem.

Comment: MaTeX outlines all text. The text ends up as normal vector graphics. The computer no longer knows that it's text, so you don't get font hinting. Therefore, depending on the PDF reader you use, and the display resolution, it may not look quite as sharp as normal text. This won't be an issue on high-resolution screens.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thanks for the reply. The problem is when I print it, I would like the font on the plot to look good and similar to the body latex text. But when I print the page containing this figure onto paper, the font clearly looks spotty.

Comment: Which PDF reader are you using when printing? Try opening your PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader and print from there. However, there might also be some issues in how you include your figure in $\TeX$.

Comment: @Domen That solved it! Thanks! I've been directly clicking on downloaded files in chrome and printing them.

Comment: @Razor, I had the same problem a few months ago when some of the vector images in my PDF were printed with low resolution. Apparently, it has to do with transparency not being handled correctly in some cases/software, forcing the image to get rasterized before printing.

Comment: @Razor That's often an issue with the printing method. Modern laser printers have very high resolutions. With a good printer, and the appropriate driver (can you use a PostScript driver?) it should print fine. I know what you mean BTW and I've seen bad print output as well. Yes, this is annoying. My point is that it's fixable, so don't give up ...

Comment: I just saw the comments from @Domen, thanks for the extra hints!

Comment: @Domen Your comment is interesting and specific enough to warrant being turned into an answer! Would y ou consider doing that so the question appears as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A solution without a satisfactory explanation

Open your PDF in **Adobe Acrobat Reader** and print it from there.

---

I've had the same issue a while ago, when *some* of the images, created with python (matplotlib) and subsequently inserted into a $\LaTeX$ document, made the whole page in which they appeared become rasterized when printed. I have not managed to find a proper explanation, but it likely has to do something with the transparency layers. However, this rasterization occurred only if I was using a built-in browser PDF reader or Foxit PDF Reader. Using Adobe Acrobat Reader, the print was fine.

There are a few questions on TeX StackExchange somehow related to this issue:

- [LaTeX rasterizes Mathematica 10 PDF figures when PDF document is printed, but not Mathematica 9 figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251957/latex-rasterizes-mathematica-10-pdf-figures-when-pdf-document-is-printed-but-no)
- [Why do some vector graphics included into a document force rasterization of the whole page and subsequently ruin the look of the text in cups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/why-do-some-vector-graphics-included-into-a-document-force-rasterization-of-the)
- [Using opacity in TikZ makes the entire page become "more coarse" when printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40050/using-opacity-in-tikz-makes-the-entire-page-become-more-coarse-when-printed)

Comment: I always use adobe PDF reader. Builtin browser readers are not as good at all. OK for browsing. But nothing else. Another problem is with latex animate package. The animation in the PDF do not run when viewed in browser PDF reader, but works fine when the PDF is downloaded and opened using Adobe PDF reader directly on the PC.